# How To Create Duplicate Records depending on Column which indicates on Repetition

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I've got a table which consisting aggregated records, and i need to Split them according to specific column ('Shares Bought' like in the example below), as Follow:

Original Table:

[image]

Requested Table:

[image]

Needless to say, that there are more records like that in the table and i need an automated query (not manual insertions),
and also there are some more attributes which i will need to duplicate (like the field 'Date').

Comment: use `cursor`.. for looping and auto inserting

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Can accomplish this using sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to first generate_rows with increasing row_number and then perform a cross join with your table.

Eg:

```
create table t(rowid int, name varchar(100),shares_bought int, date_val date)

insert into t
select *
from (values (1,'Dan',2,'2018-08-23')
            ,(2,'Mirko',1,'2018-08-25')
            ,(3,'Shuli',3,'2018-05-14')
            ,(4,'Regina',1,'2018-01-19')
            )t(x,y,z,a)

with generate_data
  as (select top (select max(shares_bought) from t)
             row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnk /* This would generate rows starting from 1,2,3 etc*/
       from sys.objects a
       cross join sys.objects b
   )
select row_number() over(order by t.rowid) as rowid,t.name,1 as shares_bought,t.date_val
  from t 
  join generate_data gd
    on gd.rnk <=t.shares_bought /* generate rows up and until the number of shares bought*/
 order by 1
```

Here is a db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5736255585c3ab2c2964c655bec9e08b

Comment: A small fix: need a `;` after the `insert` statement. A small improvement - you can do `select top(select max(shares_bought) from t) row_number...` in the cte, to select only the numbers you actually need. Other then that, +1.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a better version. I have updated the original answer. Thanks @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (rowid int, name varchar(100), sb int, dt date);
insert into @t values
(1, 'Dan', 2, '20180823'),
(2, 'Mirco', 1, '20180825'),
(3, 'Shuli', 3, '20180514'),
(4, 'Regina', 1, '20180119');

with nums as
(
select n
from (values(1), (2), (3), (4)) v(n)
)

select t.*
from @t t
     cross apply (select top (t.sb) *
                  from nums) a;
```

Use a table of numbers instead of `CTE` nums or add there as many values as you can find in Shares Bought column.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use `recursive` cte :

```
with t as (
     select 1 as RowId, Name, ShareBought, Date
     from table
     union all
     select RowId+1, Name, ShareBought, Date
     from t
     where RowId <= ShareBought
)
select row_number() over (order by name) as RowId, 
       Name, 1 as ShareBought, Date 
from t;
```

If the sharebought not limited to only 2 or 3 then you would have to use `option (maxrecursion 0)` query hint as because by default it is limited to only `100` `sharebought`.